# Make pluggable components in react native

Tags: react-native, components

Can i use react native to make pluggable components which can be inserted in to a native android app. The components should function by themselves. For example i make a search bar via react native. Is it possible to make a component only with its concerned java files which can just be plugged into an android/ios app. If yes how exactly does one do it, Note i dont want to make an entire apk or ipa file.

My use case
I have a set of api for my website. A third party wants to integrate the apis as components, is it possible for me to just make JAR/ Java class files for the component i am making and then plug the code into their codebase..

Any help or lead would be useful.

Comment: But if you need those functions for a website, why are you trying to use code which has been written for mobile?
I think you cannot do what you want, and even if there was any way, you would probably be making a big mistake.

Comment: i am trying to integrate my components into a thrid party android app, hence was wondering if this was possible..